# Iterating through ArrayList in JSP in Spring using foreach

Tags: java, spring, jsp, arraylist

I have the following code for iterating through the arrayList:

```
    <form:forEach items="${list}" var="list">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${list}" /><td>
    </tr>
</form:forEach>
```

Now, my code is iterating through the list but it is printing all the values at once instead of printing one by one as shown below:

```
[24873, 24872, 24875, 24874, 24877, 24876, 24879, 24878, 24865, 24864]
```

How can I make it work to print them line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="listNumber" varStatus="listStatus">
       <c:if test="${listStatus.index < n}">
       <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${listNumber}" /><td>
       </tr>
       </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

When you specify var also as list and access it in c out: it picks up the entire list not each element in the list. To restrict display to n values, you need to specify the number in the above code.

Comment: How can I restrict this for printing just the first n values?

Comment: use begin & end attribute of forEach tag - <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5"></c:forEach>

Comment: @Prasad: ur code helped me alot but ur new code for printing first n values isn't working..

Comment: Updated from count to index. count starts from 1 where as index from 0, so that nth element will also be included now.